# Grub "quiet splash" + linux-image-3.2.0-40-generic + full disk encryption = boot failure

Tags: 12.04, boot, grub2, encryption

From this morning the boot process on my laptop is no longer working. The only relevant change from yesterday (when all was working fine) has been a kernel update (from 3.2.0-39-generic to 3.2.0-40-generic).

When grub tries to boot the 3.2.0-40-generic kernel, I get only a black screen (the screen seems powered off).

After many tries and googling around, I found the following: if I change the CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT grub parameter (inside /etc/default/grub) from the default value "quiet splash" to "nomodeset" the boot process works but the screen has a lower resolution than before (from 1600x900 to 800x600).

This is not happening with the previous kernel version (3.2.0-39-generic). Even with "quiet splash" enabled, all is working fine with the correct resolution.

An important note: my disk is fully encrypted (actually the setup is LVM + encryption). So when the boot works fine, after the grub selection screen I am asked to insert the passphrase for decrypting the whole file system.

Is there a way to fix this misbehaviour? I would like to avoid workarounds like using always an old kernel or using "nomodeset" as a default parameter.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Any manually installed graphics drivers, ATI, Nvidia?

Comment: No,I didn't installed any graphic driver manually. Since everything was working fine out-of-the-box from the very beginning, I had no need to install any graphic driver

Comment: This sounds like a bug and should be reported as such. [How do I report a bug?](http://askubuntu.com/q/5121/88802)

Answer (score 0):

I was having that problem and after lots of time looking for what was causing t, i discovered that software manager wasn't updating initramfs leaving the boot state broken. But it only hapens with a few people. I don't know why.

Try to update the inirtramfs:

sudo update-initramfs -u

Tell-me if it worked.

**EDIT**: It seems its a bug, not in the update manager but in the kernel.
https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/1167114

Comment: Same problem on 64 bit system; update-initramfs did not help.

Comment: True. See this: https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/1167114